# Automatically redirect subdomain to folder path?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain, directory

Is it possible to automatically redirect subdomains to a folder (structure)? I want to change the setup of my site from subdomain to folder and there a lot of redirects to be done, so i was wondering if there is any automatic solution.

What i want is i.e.:

```
subfolder1.domain.com
```

to be redirected to (internal redirect, same top-level domain) `www.domain.com/folder/subfolder1`

Where 'subfolder1' is relative (not static).
So is there a general htaccess code i can use?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put this code in your htaccess (which has to be in document root folder)

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www\.).+?)\.(domain\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%2/folder/%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Note: by `redirect` in your question, i understood it as an external redirect. If that's not the case, i'll update my answer

---

EDIT (internal rewrite)

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www\.).+?)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!folder/).*)$ /folder/%1/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Sorry, its an internal redirect (same  top-level domain).